# Nodejs & Express: How to redirect to another website and not to a route in the site?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, routes

I'm trying to make a function that redirects you to another website, but instead of redirecting to another website its assuming that the weblink that i want to redirect to is a route in my website.

```
    app.get('/:shorturl', (req, res) => {
    UrlShort.findOne({'ShortUrl': req.param('shorturl')}, (err, doc) => {
        if(err) return res.send('Error Reading Database!');
        var re = new RegExp("$(http|https)://", "i");
        if(re.test(doc.OriginalUrl)){
            res.redirect(301, doc.OriginalUrl);
        } else {
            res.redirect(301, 'http://' + doc.OriginalUrl);
        }
     });
   });
```

Instead of redirecting to the other web site it redirects to this:

```
http://localhost:3000/www.google.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not redirect function. It seems true. But your Regex is wrong. You need to change your regex to

```
^(http|https)://
```

Here is working code example that I've tested:

```
app.get("/redirect", function(req, res) {
var url = "http://www.google.com";

var re = new RegExp("^(http|https)://", "i");
if(re.test(url)){
    console.log("#LOG1", url);
    res.redirect(301, url);
} else {
    console.log("#LOG2", 'http://' + url);
    res.redirect(301, 'http://' + url);
}});
```

Comment: I've edited my answer for add code example. @WackThat